# Counting age at date in mysql, with rails methods

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I'm looking to get a `.count` based format, by grouping a method on the model.
What I've tried is along the lines of

```
Model.all.group(:age_at_x).count
```

and

```
Model.all.group_by { |v| v.age_at_x }.count
```

With age_at_x defined in the model. I know that this tries to group in MySQL with a method, but I can't seem to figure out to actually group by the method?

```
def age_at_x
  date = Time.new(2016, 6, 25)
  dob = self.birth 
  date.year - dob.year - ((date.month > dob.month || (date.month == dob.month && date.day >= dob.day)) ? 0 : 1)
end
```

I'm looking to count the different ages, and see how many of each - not the number of ages.

Furthermore in the future, to count by 18+ and under 18.

Comment: then you should build SQL request with all your conditions...

Comment: That's what I though myself - I was just making sure, there wasn't any other way (easier to read-way). @OlegSobchuk

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you are trying to count people by diferentes ages, try that:

```
Model.select(:birth).distinct.count
```

Comment: But :birth is the entire date. Any way to easily just select the year? This just outputs the amount of different dates. I need to know how many of each date there is. Changed it to `Model.group("YEAR(birth)").distinct.count` which worked!

Comment: If you are recording the `birth` instead of `year`, `month` and `day`, then you must do this: `Model.select(:birth).distinct.uniq{ |birth| birth.getYear }.size`.. or implement a SQL query